# How to calculate the chemical potential for a 2D lattice gas with excluded volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, lattice-model, electrochemistry

The chemical potential of a 2D lattice gas is given by

$$\mu = k_\mathrm{B}T\ln\left(\frac{c}{(1-c)q}\right),\tag{1}$$

where $c$ is the concentration of particles on the lattice, $T$ is the temperature, $k_\mathrm{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $q$ is the per particle partition function (source: Hill's *Statistical Mechanics* [1]).

But I have come across a formula for the chemical potential with excluded volume interactions that I am having trouble deriving. The chemical potential of a 2D lattice gas with excluded volume is given by

$$\mu = k_\mathrm{B}T\ln\left(\frac{c}{(1-c)^sq}\right),\tag{2}$$

where $s$ is the number of sites excluded by a particle (source: article by Bazant [[2](https://doi.org/10/f4zkqt)]).

I will be grateful if someone could point me to a source for the derivation or give me any pointers.

#### References

1. Hill, T. L. *Statistical Mechanics: Principles and Selected Applications*; Dover Publications: New York, **1987**. ISBN 978-0-486-65390-7.
2. Bazant, M. Z. Theory of Chemical Kinetics and Charge Transfer Based on Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics. *Acc. Chem. Res.* **2013**, 46 (5), 1144–1160. https://doi.org/10/f4zkqt.